# ggplot facet plot - change y-axis tick mark text using a pattern

Tags: r, ggplot2

with a data frame like below.

```
text <- "
name,var,value
tata_zest,a,99.8
toyota_prius,a,100.0
honda_civic,a,99.9
nissan_rx4,a,10 
tata_zest,b,8
toyota_prius,b,7
honda_civic,b,11
nissan_rx4,b,13
tata_zest,c,0.2
toyota_prius,c,0.21
honda_civic,c,0.15
nissan_rx4,c,0.32
tata_zest,d,300
toyota_prius,d,400
honda_civic,d,200
nissan_rx4,d,650
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'm creating a bar plot with labels using ggplot as below.

```
ggplot() +
geom_bar(
  data=df, color = "white", stat = "identity", position='dodge',
  aes(x=name, y=value)
) + coord_flip() +
geom_text(data = df, angle = 0, hjust = 1, 
          aes(x=name, y=value, label=value) 
          ) +
facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
theme(
  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
  axis.title.y=element_blank()
  )
```

This gives a plot like below.

[image]

I need to now replace the y-axis tick mark text by trimming everything after `_` in the labels. I need a way to do this within ggplot - not in the original dataframe `df`. I'm hoping I can use something like `gsub("[_].*$", "", x)` within ggplot - how do I go about it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform()` or `dplyr::mutate()` to pass an altered version of `df` to `ggplot()` without changing the data frame:

```
ggplot(data =  transform(df, name = sapply(strsplit(name, '_'), '[', 1))) +
  geom_bar(
    color = "white", stat = "identity", position='dodge',
    aes(x=name, y=value)
  ) + coord_flip() +
  geom_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, 
            aes(x=name, y=value, label=value) 
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free", ncol = 2) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank()
  )
```

Note that I moved the `data =` argument to `ggplot()` instead of having it twice inside each of the geoms. Otherwise the `transform()` would have to be repeated twice as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `scale_*` functions, such as `scale_x_discrete` in this case, have an argument `labels` that accepts a function. You can either define the function elsewhere and set it as the `labels` argument, or you can define the function inline. The underlying data stays the same, but you change the way the labels are written:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = value)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_replace(x, "_.+$", "")) +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free")
```

Note that I opted for the `str_replace` function from `stringr`; I find it more convenient, legible, and concise than working with the base string functions, especially for something quick like labeling, but that's just a preference.